# define variable in the middle of the code could generate compilation error

Tags: c, gcc

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char buf[256];

    printf("\nString - Enter your string: ");
    scanf ("%s", buf);

    char *_S = buf;

     .....

}
```

defining `char *_S = buf;` in the middle of the code could generate compilation error in some `CXX` versions

What version of `CXX` this could generate error. and are there some option to add to the `gcc` command in order to avoid this error?

**EDIT:**

I tried with the following option and I did not get any error:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 -o test test.c
$ gcc -std=c90 -o test test.c
$ gcc -std=c89 -o test test.c
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5.2/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.5 --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --with-multiarch-defaults=i386-linux-gnu --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.5 --libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-plugin --enable-gold --enable-ld=default --with-plugin-ld=ld.gold --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.5.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 
$
```

Comment: on my system its fine in both ways, I tried `gcc -std=c99 try.c`
as well as `$ gcc -std=c89 try.c` also as `gcc try.c` all are correct

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Are you certain? It should not work with C89. What happens if you add -Wall -pedantic?

Comment: @Lundin Problematic :( ,   its long, should I post in answer?

Comment: @Lundin I posted below , I will remove after some time its not my answer

Comment: @Lundin `-std=c89 -pedantic` gives a warning (more than a diagnostic isn't required, I think), `-std=c89 -pedantic-errors` of course errors.

Comment: I'm *amazed* there isn't an implementation-dependent macro *somewhere* in the included header chain called `_S`

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell GCC to build as [C90 or earlier](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html).

```
$ gcc -std=c90 mycode.c
```

Comment: so the `CXX` should be > `C90` ?

Comment: With `-std=CXX` you ask for standard behaviour as described in C standard XX vintage (as far as GCC is capable, anyway); many of the new features in the standard were present before in GCC, to use standard as of year XX with GCC extensions use `-std=gnuXX`. Some extensions in GCC where included as is, others changed syntax or semantics, others where discarded (and will probably dissapear for GCC soonish).

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the error, compile as `-std=c99` or -`std=c11`.

By default, GCC uses "non-standard GNU goo", which typically will default to something similar to C99 in any GCC version released during the past 10 years or so. Meaning that by default, GCC shouldn't give you an error.

Answer (score 0):

C99 is the first version of the standard that allows local variables to be declared after the first non-declaring statement of a block.

So if you pass `-std=c99` to gcc, it will accept your code. Obviously, later versions of the standard also allow locals to be declared after non-declaring statements.

Comment: so the `CXX` should be >= `C99` ? and what about `C11`?

Comment: C11 also allows local variables to be declared after non-declaration statements. You can safely assuming that this feature will never be removed from future versions of the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to C99 local variable declarations must be declared at the top of a block.  If your compiler does not support C99 you can either simply use C++ compilation, or create an *unconditional statement block*

```
int main()
{
    char buf[256];

    printf("\nString - Enter your string: ");
    scanf ("%s", buf);

    // Unconditional block to localise the variable buf
    {
        char *_S = buf;

        ...
    }

    // buf no longer in scope here
    ...
}
```

Comment: @vonbrand:  Upon reflection I have changed the term to *unconditional statement block* as that seems clear and in need of no explanation.

Comment: The block by itself is never conditional. [Perhaps should look up what the standard calls this].

Comment: @vonbrand: You think? When a statement block either executes or does not execute depending on a preceding conditional control flow statment, then it is of course conditional. The block in my example is not conditional, but that is an unusual usage.  The qualifying term *unconditional* does not need sactionaing by the ISO standard to be usful in describing its purpose here in distinguishing it from the more normal usage in relation to a control flow statement.